# Issue with PostgreSQL: 'now' keeps returning same old value

Tags: postgresql, transactions, apache-commons-dbcp

I have an old web app, the relevant current stack is: Java 8, Tomcat 7, Apache Commons DBCP 2.1, Spring 2.5 (for transactions), iBatis, PostgreSQL 9.2 with postgresql-9.4.1208.jar

Part of the code inserts new records in `incidents` table, where the field `begin_date` (`timestamp(3) with time zone`) is a creation timestamp, filled with `now`:

```
    insert into incidents
    (...., begin_date,    )
    values
    (..., 'now' ....)
```

All this is executed via iBatis, transactions managed programatically via Spring, connections acquired via DBCP pool.  The webapp (actually a pair, clientside and backoffice, who share most of the code and jars) has been working since years.

Lately, perhaps after some libraries updates and reorganization (nothing important, it seemed), I've been experiencing (intermitent, hard to reproduce) some nasty problem: `now` seems to freeze, and it begins returning the same "old" value. Then, many records appear with the same creation timestamp, hours or days ago:

```
db=# select 'now'::timestamptz;
        timestamp
-------------------------
 2016-06-10 21:59:03.637+00

db=#  select rid,begin_date from incidents order by rid desc limit 6;
  rid  |         begin_date
-------+----------------------------
 85059 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
 85058 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
 85057 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
 85056 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
 85055 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
 85054 | 2016-06-08 00:11:06.503+00
```

(All the above records were actually created minutes before `2016-06-10 21:50`)

How can this happen? It might be some problem related with transactions and/or connection pooling, but I can't figure out what.
I know that '[now()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html)' is an alias of `transaction_timestamp()`, it returns the time at the start of the transaction. This would suggest that a transaction was not properly closed, and the records inserts above were written (unintentionally) in a single long transaction. But this looks rather incredible to me.

First, I can insert a new record (via the webapp) and, using a `psql` console, I see that it has been written with the same `begin_date` (if the transaction were uncommited, I should not see the new record, I have the default serialization level).

Furthermore, the `pg_stat_activity` view only shows `idle` connections.

Any cues?

Comment: What does the JDBC look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the constant (special timestamp value) **`'now'`**.
And there's the function **`now()`**.

The fact that you are mixing them freely suggests that you are unaware of the all-important difference. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN6209)

> #### Special Values
>
> PostgreSQL supports several special date/time input values for
>   convenience, as shown in Table 8-13. The values `infinity` and `-infinity`
>   are specially represented inside the system and will be displayed
>   unchanged; but the others are simply notational shorthands that will
>   be converted to ordinary date/time values when read. **(In particular,
>   `now` and related strings are converted to a specific time value as soon
>   as they are read.)** All of these values need to be enclosed in single
>   quotes when used as constants in SQL commands.

Bold emphasis mine.

And (like you mentioned yourself already), but quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> `now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()`.

And:

> `transaction_timestamp()` is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

There is more, read the whole chapter.

Now (no pun intended), since you are using the special value instead of the function, you get a different (unexpected for you) behavior with **prepared statements**.

Consider this demo:

```
test=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=# PREPARE foo AS
test-# SELECT timestamptz 'now' AS now_constant, now() AS now_function;
PREPARE
test=# EXECUTE foo;
         now_constant          |         now_function
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2016-06-11 03:09:05.622783+02 | 2016-06-11 03:09:05.622783+02 -- identical
(1 row)

test=# commit;
COMMIT
test=# EXECUTE foo;
         now_constant          |         now_function
-------------------------------+------------------------------
 2016-06-11 03:09:05.622783+02 | 2016-06-11 03:10:00.92488+02  -- different!
(1 row)
```

While you run both in the same ***transaction***, `'now'` and `now()` produce the same value. But a prepared statement is designed to last for the duration of your ***session*** (possibly across many transactions). Next time you execute the prepared statement, you'll see the difference.

In other words: `'now'` implements ***"early binding"***, while `now()` implements ***"late binding"***.

You may have introduced prepared statements and / or connection pooling (which can preserve prepared statements for a longer period of time) - both generally good ideas. But the hidden problem in your `INSERT` now starts kicking.

The "idle connections" you see indicate as much: connections stay open, preserving prepared statements.

In short: Use **`now()`**.

*Alternatively*, set the column default of `begin_date` to `now()` (not <strike>`'now'`</strike>!) and don't mention the column in the `INSERT`. Your "creation timestamp" is saved automatically.

Comment: I was suspecting something along this lines. So, under the dbcp pooled scenario, a "session", and its the preparedstatements, live practically forever?

Comment: @leonbloy: You can always [`DEALLOCATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-deallocate.html) a prepared statement (or use the functionality of your library). Generally, it's a *good thing* to prepare statements *once* and execute multiple times. Once you fix `now()`, it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is now(), not 'now'...

```
  insert into incidents
  (..., begin_date, ...)
  values
  (..., now(), ...)
```

or at least that works from a psql shell.

```
robert.kuhar=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2016-06-10 18:10:05.953661-07
(1 row)
```